# Django -- Form Field on change

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django forms to display data.

There is a HTML select field - which has 2 options a) teachers and b) Students.

Django forms:-

```
self.fields['account_type'].choices = [('student','Student'),('teacher', 'Teacher')]

self.helper.layout = Layout(
                    HTML('''<h5>Sign Up Information</h5>'''),
                    Div(
                        Field('account_type', placeholder="Account Type", css_class='form-control'),
                        css_class = 'form-group'
                    ),
```

Based on whether you select "Student" or "Teacher" you need auto populate another field - topics. How can I fire the 'onchange' event in Django forms.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are using Django Crispy forms and not plain Django forms.

If you want to set the `onchange` attribute, you should be able to just pass that as a keyword argument, as [described in the docs.](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#layout-objects-attributes)

```
Field('account_type',
      placeholder="Account Type",
      css_class='form-control',
      onchange="myChangeHander()"
)
```

A better way would be to give that element an id and to attach an event in JavaScript.

```
Field('account_type',
      placeholder="Account Type",
      css_class='form-control',
      css_id="account_type_id"
)
```

Assuming you use jQuery, you would put something like this somewhere in a `<script>` tag or JavaScript file:

```
$("#account_type_id").on("change", function() {...});
```